# how to handle app generated popups in appium

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

am using robot framework's appiumlibrary to automate an android application. i am facing an issue in handling an app generated pop up where uiautomatorviewer is unable to focus or fetch the elements of the popup.

[image: screenshot]

in the above screenshot, I want to click on individual options of popup like signature, initials, date..... i have tried clicking it using coordinates but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: ((***Appium 1.10, Android 8.1***))

Add this line to settings:

```
capability.setCapability("noReset", true);
```

From now your app will start like normal app, without setting reset what means without pop-ups and you will not have problem with focus at all.

I hope it will work also for you! :)

Comment: And how does that solve his problem? He wants to click the popup.

Comment: True - he wants to click the pop-up because "..app generated pop up". 
I had the same problem. I was fighting with pop-up, but my solution solves problem with pop-up appearing.  
I understand, it's kind of side-solution, but can help him. 
That's why I wanted shares this solution which helped me a lot! Maybe it will help him too.